# Does Visual Studio 2015 support C++ development on CentOS or Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ide

I am trying to select stable IDE to implement Network Protocol in C++ on CentOS/Ubuntu. Does Visual Studio 2015 support C++ development on CentOS or Ubuntu?

Comment: No, VS works only on MS Windows.

Comment: No VS does not work on Ubuntu But there is an alternative MonoDevelop and you can read more here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/monodevelop/info

Comment: There's some speculation that VS2015 when released will _target_ Linux. To what degree is to be seen.

Comment: VS 2015 hasn't been released yet, so calling it "stable" is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, that is what I have seen on the link http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=visual-studio-2015-linux-suppor.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, you are correct on that.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is Although Not for VS but will surely help to create a C++ projects.

Take a look at Creating C and C++ projects in `Monodevelop`

http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Creating_C_and_CPP_Projects

Comment: ...and why all other IDEs would not help?

Comment: Thank you for the information but I am afraid it did not help me on the selection as my second option was Code::Blocks. But I prefer to do on VS 2015!

Comment: @y.rahulan Then just use it? CodeBlocks is fine.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am currently using and I need to user same tool to draw UML diagram and I am not sure Code::Block will support UML diagram!